# Activator ui failing to start

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

The activator ui isn't starting the play server and it is giving me this error:

```
iloveyou@iloveyou-X501U ~/activator $ activator ui
Found previous process id: 22306
FOUND REPO = activator-local @ file:/home/iloveyou/activator/repository
Play server process ID is 22694
Oops, cannot start the server.
Configuration error: Configuration error[reference.conf: 13: Could not resolve        substitution to a value: ${spray.version}]
at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94)
```

I says 'FOUND REPO' but looking in the acitvator directory, I can't see one. I downloaded activator from the play homepage again but it is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this the first time you've run `activator`? I.e. have you tried a previous version of `activator`?

Comment: No, I've run the previous version got the same result. Although in both versions the `activator new` works, just the `ui` command gives this error.

Comment: if you try wiping your `repository` directory?

Comment: This is what I don't get, it says `FOUND REPO = activator-local @ file:/home/iloveyou/activator/repository` and yet there are only 3 files there: `activator` `activator.bat` `activator-launch-1.2.2.jar`

Comment: wiped my play/repository, same result

Comment: Hmm, weird. I can't reproduce. Sorry :(

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. This is how I solved it. Go to the folder where activator.bat is located. You will find there a file named "RUNNING_PID". Delete that file. Run activator.bat again. This should solve the problem.

Comment: This is usually found under "path-to-your-actiator/bin".

Answer (score 1):

Activator has running files in user's home directory `~/.activator/1.2.2` and a folder to each version. Try removing them.

Activator, activator.bat and activator-launch-1.2.2.jar what you mentioned are just app files and prob not the source of problem. (My setting is that i have app folder c:\app\activator-1.2.2 in my PATH, projects i create in c:\dev\play).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue.

While not the most elegant solution, I ran the command with super user privilages, as it needed to download missing libraries:

```
sudo activator ui
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.